# Disable click on some grid on easyui

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this crud table made with easyui. All work perfectly, except this one thing : disable click in some grid.

How to disable click on some grid ? My target is simple, so user can edit some grid on table.

here is my view :

```
<table id="dg_pindah" title="Tabel Pemindahan Dana" class="easyui-datagrid" data-options="iconCls:'icon-table-1',maximizable:true,collapsible:true" style="width:auto;height:420px"
            url="kas_pindah/getdata_p"
            toolbar="#toolbar_pindah" pagination="true" remoteSort="false" remoteFilter="true" sortName="" pageSize="25" pageList="[25,50,100,150,200,250,500]" rownumbers="true" fitColumns="false" singleSelect="true" showFooter="false" enableFilter="false">
                <thead data-options="frozen:true">
                    <tr>
                        <th field="status" width="110" halign="center" align="center" sortable="true" data-options="styler:cellStyler
                            ">Status Transfer</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="no_pindah" width="100" halign="center" align="center" sortable="true">No.Referensi</th>
                        <th field="dari_kas" width="70" halign="center" align="center" sortable="true">Dari Kas</th>
                        <th field="tujuan_kas" width="80" halign="center" align="center" sortable="true">Tujuan Kas</th>
                        <th field="tanggal" width="130" halign="center" align="center" sortable="true" formatter="tgl_indo">Tanggal</th>
                        <th field="uraian" width="300" halign="center" align="left" sortable="true">Uraian</th>
                        <th field="penerimaan" width="110" halign="center" align="right" sortable="true" formatter="rupiah">Jumlah</th>
                        <th field="nama_penerima" width="120" halign="center" sortable="true">Penerima</th>
                        <th field="pekerjaan" width="130" halign="center" sortable="true">Pekerjaan</th>
                        <th field="alamat" width="130" halign="center" sortable="true">Alamat</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add css pointer-event in your table

```
<table id="dg_pindah" style:"pointer-events: none;"
.....
 </table>
```

Comment: No. Just disable "some" grid, sir.

Comment: add this whatever you want to disable

Answer (score 0):

use **pointer-events: none** on the appropriate id/class. Make sure you add it to the correct id/class else it will disable the pointer-events for the entire element